# I want to know the exact concept of virtual address

Tags: operating-system

Virtual address is described as linear address in some places, and logical address in others.
I'd like to know which one is right with the clear concept of virtual address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concept of virtual addresses is that you have a fake/pretend address space and convert/map that somehow to the real/physical address space for one or more reasons (to improve flexibility, to improve portability, to improve security, etc). How this is implemented in practice doesn't really effect the theoretical concept.

For the implementation of the concept on 80x86; virtual addresses are converted into linear addresses using segmentation, then linear addresses are converted into physical addresses using paging. However; segmentation can be configured so that "virtual = linear" (by setting segment bases to zero and segment limits to max., including in 64-bit code if FS and GS are configured so that they do nothing); and paging can be disabled resulting in "linear = physical"; and if neither segmentation nor paging are used you end up with "virtual = linear = physical".

Most operating systems for 80x86 don't use segmentation but do use paging; so virtual addresses can be described as linear addresses for most operating systems (and most applications) on 80x86; but "technically can" isn't a good reason for increasing confusion and almost nobody would call them linear addresses (instead of virtual addresses) without a reason - normally you'd only see the word "linear" used if the difference might matter.

For logical addresses, I have no idea where you saw that, and without context I'd (correctly or incorrectly) assume it's related to storage space and has nothing to do with memory (e.g. "logical block address" as an alternative to "cylinder, head, sector addressing" for old hard disks).

Comment: A `selector:offset` pair, or a far pointer, on x86 is the logical address (see the intel manual). Virtual and linear addresses are synonyms on x86 with the former more strongly suggesting page translation enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The three basic concept you need to know:

Physical - An actual, specific device

Logical - A redirection to a device

Virtual - A simulated device

In ye olde days before large memory system, virtual and logical were often conflated in regard to addresses. In reality, there is no such thing as a virtual address. A logical address can map to a nothing at all, a physical address, or memory that is simulated virtually.

You can have virtual memory that is accessed by logical addresses.